# Installed New Hard Drive in Laptop, Not Being Detected, How to Troubleshoot

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, dell-inspiron

Here is how I am attaching new drive

[image]

Attached caddy to hard drive

[image]

Hard drive in laptop

[image]

I followed link given by Hard Drive vendor to replace hard drive, but I am having problems, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3q35j684CQc

Photo of Hard Drive:

[image]

I replaced hard disk (with [500GB 2.5" Laptop SSHD Solid State Hybrid Drive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076CJ257K)) on Dell Inspiron 15R 5521 Laptop based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kilZIXIRD_0 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3q35j684CQc (thanks to this community's guidance).

I tried booting through

(1) Dell's Recovery USB

(2) My Windows Recovery USB, but failed.

I even tried to attach external 1 TB hard drive, but get prompt that Windows cannot install through USB cable.

Below are the steps I took. How do I resolve this issue

**Booting through Dell's Recovery USB**

1 - Recovery USB that came with Dell Inspiron 15R 5521 Laptop
[image]

2 - Recovery and Restore screen
[image]

3 - Select Language
[image]

4 - Agree to their Terms
[image]

5 - Recovery and Restore will do following
[image]

6 - Running Diagnostic
[image]

7 - No Error Found <- I WAS HAPPY HERE!!!
[image]

8 - No Hard Disk Found :-(
[image]

**Booting through Windows 10 Recovery USB**

9 - Windows Recovery USB screen
[image]

10 - Install NOW!
[image]

11 - Setup is Starting
[image]

12 - Activate Windows
[image]

13 - Windows Agreement <- I WAS HAPPY
[image]

14 - Windows cannot find Drive :-(
[image]

15 - I attached external 1 TB Hard Drive, Windows will not Install
[image]

Comment: Does UEFI/BIOS see drive? If not double check connections. No system can work unless UEFI sees drive correctly. Have you updated UEFI to latest available.If new drive is SSD, it also may need firmware update.

Comment: What model is the disk?

Comment: Hello @harrymc I got this on, 500GB 2.5" Laptop SSHD Solid State Hybrid Drive, https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B076CJ257K/

Comment: Hello @oldfred How do I perform firmware update? You mean go to this [site](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/80097/Intel-SSD-Firmware-Update-Tool), download to USB and when prompted for drive, select USB where firmware is installed. I'm trying to research this, please guide.

Comment: I would think that the disk is broken. Try putting it maybe in an enclosure to see if it works.

Comment: @harrymc I enclosed the disk in the caddy that came alone with the original laptop. What other enclosure shall I try?

Comment: Whatever you have on hand, or try it in another computer. I meant trying it inside an external enclosure.

Comment: Do not know if hybrid drives are update-able or not. For my Samsung NVMe drive, I was able to download a bootable ISO to update drive. It was only for my model drive. Do you know actual manufacturer of drive, so can even get an update to firmware?

Comment: I am attempting to reach seller via Amazon @oldfred. I dunno the manufacturer, only the Amazon seller is HardDriveGeeks

Comment: @harrymc I may have a very old laptop on hand, gonna check.

Comment: Does not drive have label? Vendor serial number, model etc?

Comment: I'll open it up and check @oldfred. I also asked vendor through Amazon's portal.

Comment: @oldfred I updated message with photo of hard drive. There are lot of numbers. SN ZDEESJB3, Part Number 1U717D-021, CT: 2GTAK023XBM0DG, P/N: 909126-002. Any idea which drive to download. Maybe then it will work. When I contacted vendor, they only gave me link that says how to replace hard drive :-( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3q35j684CQc

Comment: @oldfred  I also sent message to Seagate. Unsure if they will reply (their website made me jump through so many hoops!) I entered my SN and website gave following product info Your Product: FIRECUDA25, Model Number: ST500LX025, Serial Number: ZDEESJB3

Comment: How are you connecting drive? I had an old SATA 60GB SSD and purchased a SATA to USB3 adapter. It worked well. But could not use an older HDD in same adapter as USB3 port did not have enough power to spin up drive. We also have seen DVD caddies that work for a DVD, but not for a HDD.

Comment: @oldfred How I am connecting the drive? I am inserting into the laptop. I am adding photos to top of the Original Post.

Comment: You keep mentioning caddy, so is that where DVD was before? Internal drive's do not normally have a caddy. And we have seen many users not able to use DVD caddy for a hard drive.

Comment: @oldfred The hard drive vendor referred to laptop's hard disk enclosure as a Caddy. What is the correct terminology? I don't believe DVD was there before. DVD drive is untouched on this laptop. I hope I am explaining properly.

Comment: Probable just the mounting brackets. I guess it then can be a called a caddy.

Comment: @oldfred I tried contacting Seagate for help and they say I need to purchase a warrenty from them. Then I tried replacing HD on [another laptop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZgi8GCn9GM) but it says NO HARD DRIVE FOUND. How do I find drivers (if any) for this HD. I also contacted vendor on Amazon, but I dunno what else to do ...

Comment: If you go into UEFI/BIOS does it show the Seagate drive? On either system? If not you need to return drive. Until drive is partitioned & formatted, it may not show much.

Comment: @oldfred Nope. When I press F12 it doesn't show any drive on either laptop

Comment: Not f12, but del or f2 on most systems.check your manual. F12 typically is boot menu & you have to have installed working system for f12 to see a drive. You UEFI BIOS menu has multiple tabs and one should show connected drives and status. If UEFI/BIOS does not show drive then it cannot be seen by any operating system.

Comment: ok @oldfred I shall try this

Comment: @oldfred not showing in BIOS :-( I see videos on accessing HD through Disk Management. How is that possible? Is there a way to connect Internal Hard Drive through external method. Sorry for dumb questions. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I have SATA to USB3 adapter. It works great for my old SSD, but HDD not ever seen. USB port does not have enough power to spin up an HDD. Some adapters have external power and may work, but some cheap ones seem to have issues with UEFI/gpt or large drives.  Double check connections, but if not shown in two systems, drive is defective & you should return it.  Double check connections are correct.

Comment: @oldfred Do you mean something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/Sabrent-External-Lay-Flat-Docking-EC-DFLT/dp/B00LS5NFQ2/)

Comment: Probably, mine did not have separate power supply. I was surprised how fast an external SSD could be. I have used USB3 flash drives for emergency boot installs & data backup. But they are slow. SSD was almost as fast as internal SSD drive and faster than internal HDD. So USB3 actually is pretty quick and its the flash drives that are slow.

Comment: Oh, well I am returning mine tomorrow (I'm past the Amazon return window, have to pay shipping for free replacement)

Comment: @oldfred I got exact replacement and it is STILL not working. What else can be the cause?

Comment: Does UEFI/BIOS not see drive. Not boot tab, probably f12, but settings probably f2 or del and then a tab that would show drive(s). And is drive set for AHCI, not RAID nor Intel RST?

Comment: ok @oldfred I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Since the drive is new, its possible that it has not been [initialized](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/initialize-new-disks).  If you have a working copy of Windows you can use the Disk Management user interface.  However, if it is the only disk in the system you need to use the command line.

At the *Where do you want to install Windows?* screen, press `Shift+F10` to bring up a command prompt.

```
diskpart
```

This should result in a `DISKPART>` prompt.  Then enter the following:

```
list disk
```

If your disk is detected you will see something like the following:

```
Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
--------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
Disk 0    Online         7452 GB  1024 KB        *
```

To initialize the disk type the following commands (assuming that you wish to use Disk 0):

```
select disk 0
clean
convert gpt
exit
```

At this point if you switch back to Setup and press Refresh your drive should now be visible.

If no drive is listed in DISKPART then you likely have a hardware issue.  Try reseating the drive, replacing the cable, using a different drive in that port or try this drive in another computer to confirm where the problem lies.

Comment: Uninitialized drive will be listed in Windows Setup though

Comment: @TomYan Windows never listed this drive :-(

Comment: Thank you for the resources @djones. I will study this and hope hope hope this will resolve issue!.

Comment: @djones I tried the steps. When I press REFRESH it did not detect the drive. However when I wanted to re-try installing Windows from bootable USB I now get screen `No boot device found. Press any key to reboot the machine`. This continues on. Help!!!

Comment: @djones When I try running Dell recovery USB I get same error as before `The Dell Recovery Process cannot continue because no hard drive was detected in your system`